# Changing the color of each element in a JSON array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I've been trying to figure this out, seems easy but for some reason I just can't get it! So I have some HTML and Vanilla JS code. It loops through several words and types them out, then deletes them. I want each word to appear on the screen in a different color. Example: "dog" is red, "cat" is blue and "monkey" is yellow. I've tried using `JSON.parse` to pull out the elements but I'm feeling like I'm going in the wrong direction. Here's my code so far:

```js
var TxtRotate = function(el, toRotate, period) {
  this.toRotate = toRotate;
  this.el = el;
  this.loopNum = 0;
  this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
  this.txt = '';
  this.tick();
  this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtRotate.prototype.tick = function() {
  var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
  var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

  if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
  } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
  }

  this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">'+this.txt+'</span>';

  var that = this;
  var delta = 300 - Math.random() * 100;

  if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

  if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
  } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
    this.isDeleting = false;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 500;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
  }, delta);
};

window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('txt-rotate');
  for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-rotate');
    var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
    if (toRotate) {
      new TxtRotate(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
    }
  }

};
```

```html
<h1 class="big-title">ANIMALS
     <span
       class="txt-rotate"
       data-period="2000"
       data-rotate='[ "dog", "cat", "monkey"]'>
     </span>
   </h1>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi Kcandle.  I was looking into this and the code seems to be outputting and deleting the animals in a loop, so, minus the colors you want, it seems to be working as far as parsing out the animal names, so I think you just need to put in the colors in your data attributes of your span and then some code to handle the colors (or however you want to do it).  If I've misunderstood your problem, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See notes in snippet

```js
//new param
var TxtRotate = function(el, toRotate, period, color) {
  this.toRotate = toRotate;
  this.el = el;
  //new prop
  this.color = color;
  this.loopNum = 0;
  this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
  this.txt = '';
  this.tick();
  this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtRotate.prototype.tick = function() {
  var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
  var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];
  //new var
  var color = this.color;
  if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
  } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
  }
  //new style attribute
  this.el.innerHTML = `<span class="wrap" style="color:${color[i]}" >`+this.txt+'</span>';

  var that = this;
  var delta = 300 - Math.random() * 100;

  if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

  if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
  } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
    this.isDeleting = false;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 500;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
  }, delta);
};

window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('txt-rotate');
  for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-rotate');
    var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
    //new var
    var color = elements[i].getAttribute('data-color'); 
    if (toRotate) {
      //new arg
      new TxtRotate(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period,JSON.parse(color));
    }
  }

};
```

```html
<!-- new data attribute -->
<h1 class="big-title">ANIMALS
     <span
       class="txt-rotate"
       data-period="2000"
       data-rotate='[ "dog", "cat", "monkey"]'  
       data-color='["red","blue","yellow"]'>
     </span>
   </h1>
```